# IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root with file provider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I am using :

```
/* to pass to dl manager https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch */
val destinationPath = contexct!!.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

as destination path to store file

```
println("$TAG , downloadAndShow >> destinationPath : $destinationPath , ${destinationPath .exists()}")
```

it prints: destinationPath
: `storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ir.vasl.datyar.lawyer/files/Download/tiny-824-۲۰۲۱-۱۰-۳۱-۱۴-۱۳-۳۲.jpg , true`

In AndroidManifest

```
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

And file_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files-path"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="Download"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

but on `onComplete`
method of dl manager listener

```
val uriFromFile = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
/* Error Line */
    FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        it,
        it.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
        File(download.file)
    )
} else Uri.fromFile(File(download.file))
```

Faced error :

IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pachagename.project/files/Download/tiny-824-۲۰۲۱-۱۰-۳۱-۱۴-۱۳-۳۲.jpg

`File(download.file).exists()` returns `true`

**Solution:**

```
val destinationPath = File(it.filesDir, "files")

<external-files-path
    name="files"
    path="files/" />
```

Comment: It does Not work, it was path="." but changed for testing

Comment: I use download manager, https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch , download.file returns file path in String

Comment: Not default download manager, check url

Comment: dude, post Updated

Comment: Actually, it works on a  project with the same library versions. but not works on  current project

Comment: Sorry, dont know. Your code looks ok.

Comment: It looks ok but not working, I Found it!